# speeding up nested ifelse statement - R

Tags: r, if-statement, nested

Example at this point in my code:

```
    time_elapsed                     network_name             daypart       day
 1:         4705                          Laff TV 2016-09-09 03:11:35    Friday
 2:         1800                              CNN 2016-09-10 08:00:00  Saturday
 3:           23                             INSP 2016-09-02 18:00:00    Friday
 4:          148                              NBC 2016-09-02 16:01:26    Friday
 5:          957                  History Channel 2016-09-07 14:44:03 Wednesday
 6:         1138         Nickelodeon/Nick-at-Nite 2016-09-09 16:00:00    Friday
 7:          120                       Starz Edge 2016-09-07 15:28:59 Wednesday
 8:          268            Starz Encore Westerns 2016-09-07 17:13:05 Wednesday
 9:            6                              CBS 2016-09-10 04:00:00  Saturday
10:           69                      Independent 2016-09-07 12:48:11 Wednesday
11:         4151                              NBC 2016-09-09 04:32:37    Friday
12:          570 PBS: Public Broadcasting Service 2016-09-07 16:17:58 Wednesday
13:         1421                            NBCSN 2016-09-03 15:22:23  Saturday
14:          466          Estrella TV (Broadcast) 2016-09-04 19:00:00    Sunday
```

(generally over 200 million rows)

I wrote the following nested ifelse statement a couple months ago when I was running my entire script over just a couple of million rows but now that I'm running it on a bigger scale I'd really like to find a way to make it a little faster.

```
targets_random$daypart <- ifelse((wday(targets_random$daypart) == 1 | 
                wday(targets_random$daypart) == 7), "W: Weekend",
                        ifelse(hour(targets_random$daypart) <= 2, "LP: Late Prime",
                        ifelse((hour(targets_random$daypart) >= 3 & 
                hour(targets_random$daypart) <= 5), "O: Overnight",
                        ifelse((hour(targets_random$daypart) >= 6 & 
                hour(targets_random$daypart) <= 9), "EM: Early Morning",
                        ifelse((hour(targets_random$daypart) >= 10 & 
                hour(targets_random$daypart) <= 16), "D: Day",
                        ifelse((hour(targets_random$daypart) >= 17 & 
                hour(targets_random$daypart) <= 20), "F: Fringe",
                        ifelse(hour(targets_random$daypart) >= 21, "P: Prime", NA)))))))
```

I tried using a data.table solution but was only very slightly faster and transformed my data.table to a list. For the life of me I couldn't see why. That added enough time to undo it wasn't worth the savings.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. What I have works and if I have to stick with it, it'll be fine. It currently takes about 3.5 hours to run through the full code. The biggest portion is a SQL query and the file creation of the results but it would be nice if I could shave off as much time as possible!

(As a sidenote - it used to be almost 8 hours before I replaced tons of parts with data.table syntax. I'm an official fan now!)

Comment: You might be able to use parLapply to run multipe rows at a time

Comment: See `?cut`. It seems that you could use something like `cut(targets_random$daypart$hour, c(-Inf, 3, 6, 10, 17, 21, Inf), include.lowest = TRUE, right = FALSE)` but changing the "labels" argument with `c("LP: Late Prime", "O: Overnight", etc...)` and, afterwards replacing with `"W: Weekend"` wherever `(targets_random$daypart$wday + 1) %in% c(1, 7)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider building a separate, static *daytimes* dataframe of all possible combinations and their result. In SQL practice, this would be considered a lookup table. Then routinely merge with full data table.

```
# DF (N=168) 7 X 24
daytimes <- expand.grid(wday=c(1:7),
                        hour=c(1:24))    
daytimes$result <- 
  ifelse((daytimes$wday == 1|daytimes$wday == 7), "W: Weekend",
       ifelse(daytimes$hour <= 2, "LP: Late Prime",
             ifelse((daytimes$hour >= 3 & daytimes$hour <= 5), "O: Overnight",
                    ifelse((daytimes$hour >= 6 & daytimes$hour <= 9), "EM: Early Morning",
                           ifelse((daytimes$hour >= 10 & daytimes$hour <= 16), "D: Day",
                                  ifelse((daytimes$hour >= 17 & daytimes$hour <= 20), "F: Fringe",
                                         ifelse(daytimes$hour >= 21, "P: Prime", NA)))))))
# CREATE MERGE FIELDS
targets_random$wday <- wday(targets_random$daypart)
targets_random$hour <- hour(targets_random$daypart)

# MERGE WITH NEW COLUMN: result
targets_random <- merge(targets_random, daytimes, by=c("wday", "hour"))
```

Comment: Ohhhh I'm going to try that!